# Am I parallelizing this right?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I basically have to obtain a certain probability distribution by sampling from a sample of 5000 matrices. So I just need to count how many times element X occurs in the position (i,j) of these 5000 matrices. Then, I save these [values and counts] in a dictionary.

That said, I thought it could be a good idea to parallelize my code, as a serial code would run incredibly slow.
The code is the following:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np


def func(N):
    d = {}

    filenames = ["file" + str(k) + ".txt" for k in range(N, N + 1000)]
    ##each of these files is a 306x306 matrix
    for i in range(306):
        data = np.vstack([np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=",", usecols=i) for f in filenames])
        for j in range(306):
            values, counts = np.unique(data.T[j], return_counts=True)
            for i in values:
                d[i] = counts[np.where(values == i)]
    return d


if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = mp.cpu_count()
    with mp.Pool(processes=N) as p:
        results = p.map(func, [m for m in range(1000, 5000, 1000)])
```

Since it is my first time parallelizing a function, I would like some feedback. Also, as this is still slow due to the fact that it has to load a 1000x306 matrix, any advice on how to improve it would be very welcome.

Comment: At the very least you shouldn't be loading data from a file in the `for i` loop, that's definitely a bottleneck. You can just slice the loaded data to simulate `usecols`.

Comment: @AKX , could you please make an example?

Comment: It seems you do not use the proper tools to do your computation. I advise you to look at HDF5 file format (or a similar one) to read/store matrices efficiently and Numba to parallelize to code more easily. Furthermore, the costly last loop (iterating over `values`) seems totally useless.

Comment: what is the size of all your files? it would make it much more efficient if they could be all loaded into memory at once

Comment: @JérômeRichard, do you suggest any simple and clear guide to learn them?

Comment: @Aaron, size is 2.5 MB each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this description:

> how many times element X occurs in the position (i,j) of these 5000 matrices

I would re-structure your code to return a 306x306 array of dictionaries which have keys for each value occurring in that position, and values for how many times that value occurs. You can then generate the data for a subset of the files in parallel, and then merge the data at the end. You should adjust the `chunksize` to load many file at once (as much as you have ram for) to reduce the number of times you have to loop manually over the array indices. Re-ordering the data into "Fortran" order should make array access more efficient (calls to `np.unique` will be faster) when accessing `arr[:,i,j]`.

```
arr_shape = (5, 5)
chunksize = 10 #load chunks of 200 files at a time
start_n = 0
end_n = 100

def func(N):
    #unpack args from input tuple
    filenames = ["file" + str(k) + ".txt" for k in range(N[0], N[1])]
    
    #load and stack all the arrays into single array
    arr = np.stack([np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=",") for f in filenames])
    #re-order data in memory for efficient access along 0th axis (not needed, but likely faster)
    arr = np.asfortranarray(arr) 
    
    res = []
    #the more arrays you can load at once (chunksize), the fewer times we have to go through this inefficient loop
    for i in range(arr_shape[0]):
        res.append(list())
        for j in range(arr_shape[1]):
            #each res[i][j] will be a tuple of (values, counts)
            res[i].append(np.unique(arr[:,i,j], return_counts=True))
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with mp.Pool() as p:
        
        #build tuples of (start, end) for chunks of arbitrary size
        chunks = []
        for start in range(start_n, end_n, chunksize):
            if start + chunksize > end_n:
                end = end_n
            else:
                end = start + chunksize
            chunks.append((start, end))
            
        #build array of dicts to merge results into
        d = []
        for i in range(arr_shape[0]):
            d.append(list())
            for j in range(arr_shape[1]):
                #each d[i][j] will be a dict of d[value] = count
                d[i].append(defaultdict(int)) #empty values default to 0
                
        #call our "func" in parallel, and get any results as they come in.
        for res in p.imap_unordered(func=func, iterable=chunks):
            #merge the results into d
            for i in range(arr_shape[0]):
                for j in range(arr_shape[1]):
                    #recall result is array of tuples of (values, counts). zip() is an easy way to get them in pairs
                    for value, count in zip(res[i][j][0], res[i][j][1]):
                        d[i][j][value] += count
```

Comment: Thank you! This could work, (substituting `end_n` with `end` here ` end_n = start + chunksize` ) however, I am a bit confused here:
`zip(res[i][j][0], res[i][j][1])`
if res is a 2D array, what does that third index stand for? Also, it gives me the list index out of range error for this line

Comment: @Benny res is not strictly a 2d array. It is an array of the results of the `np.unique` call, which is a tuple of 2 numpy arrays. `res[i][j][0]` is the first numpy array in the tuple which is the unique values, and `res[i][j][1]` is the second numpy array in the tuple which is the counts of those values. As for the out of range, idk because I didn't fully test the code, so I was kinda firing from the hip. I suppose I could generate some test data to test with if you could post an example of what yours looks like.

Comment: @Benny I found the bugs after generating some test data. I was not appending to the inner list where I should have been. (I also had a wrong variable name generating the chunks: `end = start + chunksize`) see edit....